# How do I customize the template used by Visual Studio 2012 when a new file is added to a project on a solution level?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I add a file using the "Add New" context menu, I get a screen where I can select various predefined templates.

Can I replace or add to(replace preferred) these templates on a solution level in such a manner that everyone working on any project in the solution gets the same templates? (We are using TFS though cannot perform admin level actions on it, and specifically this is a database project)

Comment: So you have a report template that you want to use for new reports, is the template you've made an rdl file?

Comment: @CLockeWork I'm not talking about report templates specifically, example: if I add a stored procedure, the file is populated with a specific built in template. We use a different template in our team. I wanted to configure VS so that the template our team uses for SP's,functions,etc appears by default

Comment: This *may* point you in the right direction: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Spackle/72869/

Comment: @CLockeWork  Thanks, that kind of solves the problem since I can do it for my personal machine but would not allow it to be propagated to the entire team without repeating the steps locally on each machine. I wonder if Visual Studio even allows this...

Comment: I'm not sure, I certainly can't find a way. We keep any template items--report templates, default shared datatsets, etc...--in a seperate project in the same shared solution and just copy/paste them into whatever project we want to add them to.